# How can I stop the server thread(and may activate it later)?

Tags: java, sockets, server

I'm creating a multithread server that will receive message from client, process and send back the result.

The problem is when I want the server thread to stop, it won't.

Even setting the `stopFlag=true`, the client is still can connect to server and get the result.

How can I stop the server thread(and may activate it later)?

I tried all of these below but they didn't work.

[Close listening ServerSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120986/close-listening-serversocket)

[Java server socket program after one day it stops listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055947/java-server-socket-program-after-one-day-it-stops-listening)

[Close listening ServerSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120986/close-listening-serversocket)
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

```
public class ServerStart implements Runnable{

private JTextArea servLog;
private boolean stopFlag=false;
public ServerStart(JTextArea servLog){
    this.servLog=servLog;
}

public void setStopFlag(boolean stop){

    stopFlag=stop;

}


@Override
public void run() {
    int port=444;
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);

        synchronized(this){
            while(!stopFlag){
                Socket clientSock=null;
                try{
                clientSock = serverSock.accept();



                }catch(IOException e){
                    if(stopFlag){
                    System.out.println("Server stop");    
                    return;
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);

                }
                Thread listener = new Thread(new Socket_test(clientSock, port,servLog));
                listener.start();
            }

                serverSock.close();
        }




    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerStart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's good that you mention what you have already tried, but please also add what exactly didn't work when you tried each of those solutions.

Comment: Well, they don't show any error. The client and server run fine. 

The only problem is that somehow I can't close the server thread even I set the stopFlag.

Comment: Did you really try the third solution *exactly*? Including the fact that there are *synchronized methods* in it?

Comment: YES, 

The third solution put setSoTimeout and one comment suggest to  close the server socket.

But it didn't work, so I removed them and tried something else.

This code is the lastest one I have.

Comment: No, the third solution used a synchronized method to set the stopping variable. Therefore the stopping variable's value would be visible to the server thread. That's the main point in that solution. Though simply using `volatile` would probably work as well.

Comment: Setting the stopflag to volatile static works for me, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interrupt your socket `accept()` method which is waiting on something to read from the client.  A timeout on the accept could do, or calling [close() from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method)

Secondly, your `stopRun` variable should be volatile so it can be seen on other threads when [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java).